# Ограничить количество выводимых новостей RSS

Tags: php, rss

Всем привет. Помогите советом. Есть код парсера RSS Но вываливает абсолютно все новости. Как сделать, чтобы выводил только 5 штук?

```
$feed = "http://static.feed.rbc.ru/rbc/logical/footer/news.rss";
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feed);
foreach ($sxml->attributes() as $key => $value) {
}
foreach ($sxml->channel->item as $item){ if ($key == 2) break;
    $strtemp = "<p><a href=\"$item->link\">"."$item->title</a> <span class=\"time\" style=\"font-size:11px;color:#555;\">".date("d.m.Y",strtotime($item->pubDate))."</span></p>\n";
    echo $strtemp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($sxml->channel->item as $item){
if ($i > 5 ) break;

if ($key == 2) break; 
$strtemp = "<p><a href=\"$item->link\">"."$item->title</a> <span class=\"time\" style=\"font-size:11px;color:#555;\">".date("d.m.Y",strtotime($item->pubDate))."</span></p>\n";
echo $strtemp;

$i++;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!! Заработало!

Comment: Для справки - Для чего вам это? if ($key == 2) break; foreach ($sxml->attributes() as $key => $value) {
}

Comment: На другом ресурсе посоветовали так сделать, но не помогло

Comment: удалить, это не нужный код!